# Gather existing RSS feed data using Python zap

Tags: zapier

I have an "Action" Zap which is the RSS Zap. Then the next "Action" Zap is a Run Code/Run Python Zap.

I would like the Python Zap to send all the existing feed entries in the RSS feed as data (photo data) from the RSS feed to a Google spreadsheet Zap or possibly Dropbox zap.

Basically I'd like to enter the RSS feed and the zap sends all the existing entries to a spreadsheet or Dropbox (image upload).

I've been able to collect the first entry from a feed using:

```
import re
values = re.sub('(^,+|,+$)', '', input_data['values'])
return [{'values': values}]
```

With 'values' being the image URL to collect the image. But I'd like to send every RSS feed entry URL to the next Zap

What do I need to change here? Thanks for your help!

Edit: Update

This is what I'm imagining

```
1. User Submits RSS Feed via form on website
2. Zap triggered
3. RSS feed app activated
4. Python app gets RSS feed info
4b. Python app extracts images and titles from every current entry on the RSS feed
4c. Python app send all extracted images and titles to Dropbox app
5. Dropbox app collects (via upload option) all images and text from the Python app in the folder
```

To key to this being the Zap captures everything that is currently in the RSS feed, instead of simply being ready to capture items as they come into the RSS feed.

Comment: To clarify, you've got a 3 step zap, right? some trigger,. RSS action, code action? Also do you want to send each image through once? It sounds like your current setup will send duplicates (eg. image A, then image A and B, then image A, B, and Chris). Is that what you want, or should each image flow through once?

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I just started teaching myself basic Python last week. I would like to send each image in the feed once. So if there are 12 images in the RSS feed (each their own post entry), I would like all 12 sent as individual photos to Dropbox or as a link to spreadsheet.

Comment: Got it. The easiest thing is probably to forego python entirely and just use zapier. You could make a second zap with an rss trigger. That way it handles the deduplication for you. If you wanted to use python, use that as the action after the rss trigger. Your code will get called with a single image and never miss one.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I'm looking to do something a little different. I'd like to pull all of the images in an RSS feed on one zap, not just one image at a time as they come in. So essentially the one Zap runs and every photo already in the RSS feed is sent to Dropbox or another service. That's where I thought Python would be my best bet. Is this something that could even be done?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following - is it important that they all go at once? An RSS feed is meant to update with new items as they come in, not act like a complete list of all items. Could you update your question with a concrete example and an overview of the zap(s) you're picturing in your head?

Comment: I just updated the question above. Thanks again for your help. I guess I just need the Python code that would send the signal to the Dropbox App to capture every image and text (or anything else I wanted to select in the RSS feed).

Comment: ah! so if you're getting the first value you want with the code as written, you might actually be done. Zapier has a secret feature where when a code step returns an array, downstream steps fire for each returned item. It doesn't make sense in the editor (it only shows the first item; hence why it's secret), but if you turn the zap on and trigger it for real, it should work as expected. Can you give that a shot?